# RxJava - flatMap on the same thread

Tags: rx-java2

I have nested items in my database like e.g. house - rooms. If I delete a house I also want to delete all rooms, but I do not want to think about this, so the house must know this. So my setup would look something like this:

```
fun deleteHouse(item: House): Single<House> {
    houseObservable // emits List<House>
        .take(1)
        .map { 
            DBManager.beginTransaction()
            it
        }
        .flatMapIterable { it }
        .flatMapSingle { deleteRoom(it) }
        .toList()
        .map { 
            DBManager.deleteWithoutDependencies(item)
            DBManager.endTransaction()
            item
        }
}

fun deleteRoom(item: Room): Single<Room> {
    roomObservables // emits List<Room>
        .take(1)
        .map { 
            DBManager.beginTransaction()
            it
        }
        .flatMapIterable { it }
        .flatMapSingle { DBManager.deleteWithoutDependencies(item) }
        .toList()
        .map { 
            DBManager.endTransaction()
            item
        }
}
```

**Problem**

Every item is deleted on `RxComputationThread-1` and every `beginTransaction` and `endTransaction` as well, **BUT** the last `endTransaction` that finished the deletion of the house.

I need to run all database actions on the same thread, otherwise the database will lock itself out...

Any ideas how to solve this?

**Idea**

Pass the used `Schedular` to the functions and use the same in the `flatMaps`, but is this really necessary to solve this problem?

Comment: Create a single-threaded `Scheduler` and apply `observeOn` just before those `map`s and most likely `subscribeOn` on `deleteWithoutDependencies`.

Comment: I'll try that. Additionally I've created a complete example that fully matches my real use case here: https://github.com/MFlisar/tests/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/michaelflisar/tests/tests/RxMapTest.kt The weird thing is that the example works perfectly fine - everyting is done on the same thread. Is this just by chance?

Comment: I tried using observing on `Schedulers.single()` on the most outer stream AND before each map that begins/ends a transaction and before each map in which an item is deleted from the database and this works. Not using any schedulars midstream and only using `Schedulers.single()` on the outer most stream is not enough. Weird, because in my github demo I can see that ALL maps are executed on the same thread, the one passed to the main streams `observeOn` function...